# combing two layers dissolve and simplify

Tags: arcgis-desktop, kml, dissolve

I am trying to combine a dissolve with a simplify polygon layer I've created. When doing conversion of layer to kml it says I have too many vertices hence the need for simplification. How can this be done?

Comment: Simplifying polygons can cause a lot of problems if you don't get your tolerance right.. there is Simplify Polygon http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//007000000011000000 and Generalize http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001v00000006000000.htm that use similar options and algorithms, have a read of both and see if this will fit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question:

1. Combine your 2 layers with the [Merge](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000055000000) tool
2. Just like [Michael Miles-Stimson](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/15054/michael-miles-stimson) said, use the [Simplify
   Polygon](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//007000000011000000) or the [Generalize](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001v00000006000000.htm) tool to decrease the number of
   vertices
3. Use the [Layer to KML](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00120000004n000000) tool to make the conversion